# I cant open any RootViewController.m in Xcode 4 (RootViewController.m and other files.m)? Please give me advice!!! Received below message

Tags: xcode4

Process:         Xcode [1224]
Path:            /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.0.2 (99)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-990000~53
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [92]

Date/Time:       2011-04-27 03:15:13.137 +0600
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          424202 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           35
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  121609 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   22
Anonymous UUID:                      53A8CDA1-C508-4165-9B4E-5B53859E43EE

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked basic things? Like, is your file readable and writable by the user using Xcode? Try to open it with TextEditor to see. Or maybe your memory has run out. If Xcode somewhere uses `malloc()` and it returns NULL because memory has ran out, and later tries to fill the non-existing data pointer a SIGABRT can occur.